# RegEx for replacing a JavaScript pattern

Tags: javascript, java, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I have tons of html files with expression like this:

```
eval('enterData.style.pixelTop=' + y);
```

and I want to eliminate the eval expression and just execute the code, in other words change it to:

```
enterData.style.pixelTop =  y;
```

Can anybody help me with this. Im breaking my head trying to get a solution but i only know how to eliminate the eval with:

```
Regex: eval\('(.*)'\)
Replace: $1
```

Im using java for regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know nothing about Javascript, but this is what I see.

You need to escape your `'` characters and to put them in non-matching groups using `:?`

```
Regex: eval\(((?:\')(.*)(?:\').*)\)
Replace: $1
```

Check out [regex101](https://regex101.com/) for prototyping regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that we could capture both desired `vars` separately with an expression such as:

```
.+'(.+?)'\s+?[+\-*]+\s+([a-z]+).+
```

We can surely simplify this expression, but I was not sure about other inputs that we might have.

#### Java

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = ".+'(.+?)'\\s+?[+\\-*]+\\s+([a-z]+).+";
final String string = "eval('enterData.style.pixelTop=' + y);\n"
     + "eval('enterData.style.pixelTop=' + x);";
final String subst = "$1$2;";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

System.out.println(result);
```

#### Test

```js
const regex = /.+'(.+?)'\s+?[+\-*]+\s+([a-z]+).+/gm;
const str = `eval('enterData.style.pixelTop=' + y);
eval('enterData.style.pixelTop=' + x);`;
const subst = `$1$2;`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2vSadI/1/)

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified/changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/2vSadI/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]